# What are some cards that allow for returning Monsters to my hand?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I'm looking for cards that allow me to *return* one or more *Monster Cards* from my own side of the field *to my hand* repeatedly. By repeatedly, I mean that they can be used several times per turn, including with some workaround. An example of what cards fit my needs is **Genex Ally Birdman**, who returns one face-up *Monster Card* to Special Summon itself, then if I somehow get it back into my hand, I can use it again (and yes, I'm aware it banishes itself, there are still ways to get it back).

What I'm **not** looking for:

- *Trap Cards*. I need cards that work immediately.
- Cards that return any number of *Monster Cards* once. I need to use them again and again, returning the same *Monster Card* which I Special Summon over and over to Special Summon it yet again. Returning all at once doesn't help unless I can do it as often as I like.
- Cards that return a specific *Monster Card*. I need to return generic *Monster Cards*.

Also, Monsters that must be *Normal Summoned* are of limited use unless their effect can be used as often as I like. **Swap Frog** comes to mind, but he's more or less useless because he returns either himself or exactly one Monster and that's it.

For some context, and to make it easier to evaluate whether your idea fits the requirements, here's the intended in-game purpose of this: I want to re-use cards like **Spell Striker**, **Black Luster Soldier - Envoy of the Beginning** or **Trap Eater** in order to banish all Spells/Monsters from my GY/eat all the Traps.

Comment: I feel that with such many requirements such card is unlikely to exist. At least not one that you can use over, and over and over again on the same turn, because that would be really unbalancing to the game (possibly even forbidden eventually)... I'll try to search for options for you

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd say Penguin Soldier falls into your "what I'm not looking for", but as you mentioned SwapFrog it just came to my mind, that I used to have two penguin soldiers sending back each other and a second card.

Your very specific need might not be satisfied by it, but it actually sounds like there is no 'perfect' card for you?

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't work if you have a specific archetype you want to use, but the U.A. archetype fits your needs pretty well. The monsters special summon themselves by returning one other U.A. monster to the hand. This effect allows you to summon your offensive U.A. monsters on your turn to attack, and summon your defensive U.A. monsters after your battle phase to defend against your opponent.

Answer (score 0):

A complete list of such cards would be to extensive (and prone to change) to place in an answer here. However, I suggest you take a look at [All the cards that return a card(s) from the field to the hand](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Returns_from_field_to_hand) from YuGiOh Wikia, which contains the complete list of such cards.

Some of them will surely meet your criteria.

---

Now, based on my own memory and experience I have some options to suggest:

- [Mist Valley Shaman](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Mist_Valley_Shaman): It's great because each turn you can use it's effect of returning. It's also wind, which combos great your [Genex Ally Birdman](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Genex_Ally_Birdman) will gain ATK when using it's effect.

  > Once per turn, you can return 1 other monster you control to the hand, to have this card gain 500 ATK until the End Phase.
- Other cards from the [Mist Valley](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Mist_Valley) archetype have similar effects, like [Mist Valley Thunder Lord](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Mist_Valley_Thunder_Lord), which get the same ATK and is even able to active it's effect as quick-effect (meaning also during your opponent's turn):

  > Once per turn, you can select 1 card you control. Return it to the hand, and this card gains 500 ATK until the End Phase. This effect can be activated during either player's turn.

Comment: I'm confused. In your comment to the question, you say such cards might not even exist, yet here you say a list of them would be too extensive. I did check that list on Wikia, and was exhausted quickly after sifting through dozens of cards that only very loosely have anything to do with returning cards to the hand. The point of this question is to get help from people who are actively aware of such cards without having to look through a complete list of every card that even mentions returning to the hand.

Comment: @scenia yes, I am an active YGO player, thus why I inculded such exhaustive link. I also included cards that I have direct experience with, and that fit OPs description. I said it was hard... but I proved myself wrong :)